# Dynamic models for django 1.9

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to write an app with stripped functionality of phpmyadmin using django 1.9.

The end user should be able to define and modify sql tables using web interface.

For an existing table I have managed to dynamically create and use a model:

```
def get_model(name, dict_of_fileds):
    mytype = type(name, (models.Model,) dict_of_fields)
    return mytype
```

where `dict_of fields` looks like

```
dict_od_fields = {'Title':models.CharField(max_length=500),...}
```

However, I cannot find a reliable way to create and alter tables dynamically.

After some googling found django-mutant however it fails to migrate and, hence, does not seem to be a reliable solution.

I think that since django's makemigrations/migrate commands generate create and alter statements, there should be a way to call that functionality runtime.

Comment: Consider SQLAlchemy instead of Django ORM, because `sqlalchemy.sql` maps 1:1 to SQL. You can use SQLSoup for introspection of existing tables.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine.... I am currently attempting to implement very similar functionality. I have not found solid examples of django-mutant so I am currently thinking pure SQL is the best way to accomplish dynamic tables, where I am just going to drop the django model implementation for portions of my project and work  with pure SQL Queries. Are you stating sqlalchemy and SQLSoup can still allow ORM even if DB tables are altered outside of the ORM/model declaration? - This seems unclear to me because I am not familiar with sqlalchemy at the moment

Comment: @ViaTech sqlalchemy is a great ORM and I prefer to use sqlalchemy.sql over  building SQL queries out of string concatenation/interpolation. It does not work with the Django admin though.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine cool, thanks!  I will check it out. Yeah I am not using Django Admin, I needed more complex functionality so I'm building this portion of my project in a custom manner.